# phpMyAdmin SQL Import for Dummies

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin

All I want to do is move a MySQL database from one server to another.

**Original Server:**  phpMyAdmin v2.5.4 and MySQL v4.0.20

**Destination Server:**  phpMyAdmin v3.3.9.2 and MySQL v4.1.22

In phpMyAdmin on the **original** server, I easily exported a database file in SQL format leaving all the default values alone.  The sql file is 428 KB.  I have not opened or altered this file in any way whatsoever.

In phpMyAdmin on the **destination** server, I go to the Import Tab, again leaving all default values alone, and choose my file.  The upload indicator just spins **forever** but nothing happens... nothing at all... in fact, my network monitor doesn't even show any packets moving.

I've tried in both Safari and Firefox with the same results.

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this.  I thought phpMyAdmin was supposed to make simple things like this easier.

Any suggestions?

**Thank-you!**

---

**EDIT:**  I did the import by "cut & paste" as suggested in the correct answer below.

I then quickly realized I failed to create the destination database *before* the import!  I just thought that would occur upon import.  Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than exporting your database as a FILE...simply export the commands to the screen as text that you can then copy/paste to the new phpMyAdmin.  You can do this as a single large batch...no need to separate out the queries.  Just paste the string of queries into the SQL box on the new install and it will execute all statements.

Comment: I'm pretty inexperienced with this... can you provide more step-by-step details?

Comment: Never mind.  Your suggestion worked perfectly and I also figured out my original malfunction.